# Generic handling of XML element's children

Tags: xml, xslt

Assuming we have the following XML...

```
<FruitBasket>
    <Basket>
        <Apple>1</Apple>
        <Banana>2</Banana>
        <Orange>3</Orange>
    </Basket>
    <Basket>
        <Avocado>1</Avocado>
        <Lemon>2</Lemon>
    </Basket>
</FruitBasket>
```

Using a XSLT how would I generate the following transformation?

```
<BasketContents>
    <Content>
        <FruitName>Apple</FruitName>
        <FruitAmount>1</FruitAmount>
        <FruitName>Banana</FruitName>
        <FruitAmount>2</FruitAmount>
        <FruitName>Orange</FruitName>
        <FruitAmount>3</FruitAmount>
    </Content>
    <Content>
        <FruitName>Avocado</FruitName>
        <FruitAmount>1</FruitAmount>
        <FruitName>Lemon</FruitName>
        <FruitAmount>2</FruitAmount>
    </Content>
</BasketContents>
```

I would need to do so generically, without knowing what type of fruit is in the basket The xslt would have to handle any child element of "Basket". For instance, I would not know whether the basket contained an apple or avocado, nor would I know how many types of fruit are in the basket.

Basically, this breaks down to needing to know how to call the names of child elements, so from the XML's `<Basket>` element, I could possibly apply a template to get the names of it's unknown child  elements.

Sorry if the analogy is more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fruit names don't repeat (or if a repeating fruit name is to produce two `FruitName`, `FruitAmount` pairs), then something like this should do what you need:

```
<xsl:template match="/FruitBasket">
  <BasketContents>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </BasketContents>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Basket">
  <Content>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Content>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Basket/*">
  <FruitName>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  </FruitName>
  <FruitAmount>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </FruitAmount>
</xsl:template>
```

If you need to detect multiple occurrences of a given fruit and sum their contents, then you will want to read up on grouping in a good reference source on XSLT.  In XSLT 1.0, the keyword to look for in the index is "Muenchian grouping".  In XSLT 2.0, grouping is simpler (there are group-by constructs).